# Alternative solution to underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have created a game that is based on a grid being populated with words

In my code I have a small bit of underscore.js that helps my words fit in the space available in the grid without breaching the grids barriers.

I understand that it is very powerful java script and don't personally have a problem with it. But my team manager would like to get rid of it for some jQuery that will provide the same solution as there is only one function and would save me having a whole library. How I would replace this with some jQuery?

```
function getWordToFitIn(spaceAvail, wordlist) {
    var foundIndex = -1;
    var answer = _.find(wordlist, function (word, index) {
        if (word.length <= spaceAvail) {
            foundIndex = index;
            return true;
        }
    });
    if (foundIndex == -1) {
        answer = getXSpaces(spaceAvail);
        _.find(wordlist, function (word, index) {
            if (word[0] == " ") {
                foundIndex = index;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    if (foundIndex != -1) {
        wordlist.splice(foundIndex, 1);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Study the source code. http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Comment: I have had a look. I understand what it is doing I just don't know how to go about replacing it. @user1689607

Comment: Which part don't you understand? *(Seems like I've had this conversation with you in the past.)*

Comment: I don't understand how I would make the words populating the grid take a new position if there was not enough space. @user1689607

Comment: So the _.find. What would be the jQuery equivilent? @user1689607

Comment: Just use a `for` loop, or the typical jQuery iterator. If you don't know what that is, then you need to learn jQuery.

Comment: @user1689607: …or even better, learn JavaScript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only underscore method youre using is `_.find`. But I don’t think you are using it as it was intended. It looks like you are simply looping and returning true when a criteria is met.

You can use the native `forEach` if you don’t have legacy support, or use a shim. Or you can use the `jQuery.each` method.

The first loop could *probably* (I’m not 100% sure about the `answer` variable) be written like this:

```
var answer;
$.each(wordlist, function(index, word) {
    if (word.length <= spaceAvail) {
        foundIndex = index;
        answer = word;
        return false; // stops the loop
    }
});
```

And the second one:

```
$.each(wordlist, function (index, word) {
    if (word[0] == " ") {
        foundIndex = index;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the last bit? Does it stay the same? @David

Comment: @Milo-J what last bit? The rest is native javascript as far as I can see.

Comment: @Milo-J: Maybe you should try it and find out.

Comment: @David: In the first block, instead of `answer = true`, do `answer = word`.

Comment: @user1689607 as I see it, `_.find` returns the first return value from the function, so `answer` should be true or undefined, depending on if the criteria is met.

Comment: @David: I'm pretty sure the first time a truthy return value is returned it returns the current value from the Array. Like `Array.prototype.filter`, but with only the first result.

Comment: @Milo-J These code snippets should be able to replace your existing underscore loops, just like you asked. Why it "doesn’t work" is up to you to find out, or at least do some decent debugging on your own so you know what to ask